# Recreate this view from overcast

Tags: ios, uitableview, storyboard

[image]
I love overcast and am getting into iOS development. I see this style of screen a lot.

From what I gather this is a table view with cells and then headers but how is the part at the bottom added in and also the subtitle pieces of text below each row.

I can't seem to find a way in storyboard to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can drag a `UIView` object into your `UITableView` instance in Interface Builder and then configure it the way that you want to.

When you drag a `UIView` into your `UITableView`, just drag it to the top, just above the top-most `UITableViewCell` in your `UITableView` to create a header. To create a footer, just drag it below the intended `UITableViewCell`. You can then resize the view and lay it out to your content.

Also, if you would like to do it programmatically, have a look at the `UITableViewHeaderFooterView`.

You can also create header views and footer views for sections by implementing methods of the `UITableViewDelegate` protocol such as: `tableView:viewForHeaderInSection:` and `tableView:viewForFooterInSection:`.